# Launching an external GUI application from Python via crontab

Tags: python, shell, cron, raspbian

Good afternoon!

I have a need in Raspbian to run a GUI application using a telegram bot (Python). Running the application works like this:

```
p = Popen (["/home/pi/Downloads/reaper_linux_armv7l/REAPER/reaper"], stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
```

There is one problem. If the bot was launched from crontab at system boot (@reboot),
then the external application runs in the background. It works in the background, but I can't see its interface through realVNC.

If the bot was launched manually (without crontab), then everything is fine, in which case I can see the interface of the application being launched.

Can you please tell me how launching a Python bot through crontab affects whether the application is launched in the background or not, and how can this be controlled?

Comment: Crontab is meant for programs to run in the background. If you use GUI then you will have access to the terminal, so what is the need for crontab?

Comment: Crontab is used for autolaunching Python telegram bot at system startup. Bot peforms several tasks. One of the tasks is to launch GUI app when I need it. 
Anyway problem is solved by using DISPLAY=:0 in crontab thanks to the advice below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron run in a specific environment, without display manager. If you try to do a echo $DISPLAY return null.
You need to set DISPLAY in your command, like that:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 <YOUR-COMMAND>
```

if your display is not 0, you can find, in X server with `ps aux | grep Xorg`